# jQuery click event not firing on mobile tap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a pseudo-button that acts to open/close a mobile menu:

```
<div id="top-nav-mobile-toggle">
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</div>
```

To open and close the menu, I have:

```
$('#top-nav-mobile-toggle').click(function() {
  $('.top-nav-menu').slideToggle();
});
```

It works fine on a desktop (using a mouse) but when I tap on a touchscreen device, it doesn't work.

Is there any way to get this to reliably work on a touchscreen device without using a large jQuery plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to :

change your html code to include a tag :

```
<div>
    <i class="fa fa-bars">
        <a href="#" id="top-nav-mobile-toggle"></a>
    </i>
</div>
```

in javascript/jQuery code use return false to stop bubbling :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#top-nav-mobile-toggle').click(function() {
        $('.top-nav-menu').slideToggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.on("click touchstart")` instead of `.click`. This working for me.

```
$('#top-nav-mobile-toggle').on("click touchstart", function() {
  $('.top-nav-menu').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: I tested on Safari.